# Number of logins per user per day in a date range

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I saw many posts around that area, but couldn't find the exact one.
I have a table that registers all of users logins to my app and it contains two columns - userID and timeOfLogin. It looks like that:

```
userID, timeOfLogin
1     , 14-01-10 00:07:38
2     , 14-01-10 01:28:45
3     , 14-01-10 01:28:45
1     , 14-01-09 02:04:08
1     , 14-01-09 06:14:54
etc....
```

I want to have a table that counts the number of unique user logins per day since a specific "day1" that I define in the query (day2 is the following day and so on). The table should look something like:

```
userID, numOFLogins day1, numOfLogins Day2, numOfLogins Day3, ...., numOfLogins DayN
1     ,      10         , 12              , 0               , ...., 12
2     ,      3          , 6               , 7               , ...., 15
132   ,      0          , 5               , 9               , ...., 14
```

Comment: Why do you want to have "Column" for each day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select userId,
       sum(date(timeOfLogin) = date(@day1)) as NumLogins_0,
       sum(date(timeOfLogin) = date(date(@day1) + 1)) as NumLogins_1,
       sum(date(timeOfLogin) = date(date(@day1) + 2)) as NumLogins_2,
       sum(date(timeOfLogin) = date(date(@day1) + 3)) as NumLogins_3,
       sum(date(timeOfLogin) = date(date(@day1) + 4)) as NumLogins_4
from table t
group by userId;
```

In MySQL, `date(timeOfLogin) = @day1` is treated as a `0` when the expression is false and `1` when it is true.

I'm just using `@day1` to represent your variable for the date, whatever that is.

This will work for a fixed number of columns (such as the 5 days shown above).  If you want a variable number of columns, then you cannot do this with a simple SQL statement.  You will need to construct the SQL in a string, use `prepare`, and execute it.

Comment: I would just add a where clause to limit the date range they were attempting, otherwise it would be a waste to run through 2 yrs worth of logins for only 5 days being tested for.

Comment: @DRapp . . . I agree.  Assuming there is an index on `timeOfLogin`.  However, the OP would need to be careful to keep the `where` clause aligned with the `select`, should s/he decide to add more columns.

Comment: Thx Gordon, I tried to execute it this way:     select userId,
       sum('2014-10-01' = @day1) as NumLogins_0,
       sum(date(timeOfLogin) = date(@day1 + 1) as NumLogins_1,
       sum(date(timeOfLogin) = date(@day1 + 2) as NumLogins_2,
       sum(date(timeOfLogin) = date(@day1 + 3) as NumLogins_3,
       sum(date(timeOfLogin) = date(@day1 + 4) as NumLogins_4
from loginsperuser
group by userId; And keeps getting: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; - Any idea?

Comment: How is `@day` declared?

Comment: Oh yes, this small thing of declaring the @day :-) ok so I've done it and also changed the date() to DATE_ADD() and it works, BUT, for some reason I get only the first results with numberic values, but when trying to move on to the next page all other results are NULL. When I get back to the 1st screen again, all the results are NULL as well. When trying to import the table, I get all the results as NULL in the csv. I guess that it has to do with phpmyadmin rather than with the query?

Comment: @user3306764 . . . That does sound more like a phpadmin issue than a query issue.